# Onde o diretório mediafiles deve ficar na configuração do Django para conseguir fazer o download dos arquivos no servidor Heroku (App gratuíto)?

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku, django-templates, django-admin

Após fazer upload do arquivo durante horas consigo fazer o download dos arquivos, porém passando um tempo não consigo mais fazer o download dos arquivos, dizendo que o arquivo não existe, só que quando consulto o banco de dados e a tabela pelo heroku pg:psql os arquivos ainda aparecem lá.

Alguém pode me ajudar? É problema na configuração e no código?

Usei para fazer deploy esse tutorial: https://github.com/Gpzim98/django-heroku

python-3.8.1
Django==3.0.5

Segue imagem da configuração:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Tens de implementar um solução que carrega para um bucket ou blob storage, [AWS](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html) ou [Azure](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/1.6.5/backends/azure.html) ou [GCS](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/1.6.5/backends/gcloud.html), e armazena na base de dados o path/nome da image/ficheiro.

Aqui está a explicação completa da [documentação](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted) do Heroku:

- O sistema de arquivos Heroku é efêmero - isso significa que quaisquer
  alterações no sistema de arquivos enquanto o dyno estiver em execução
  duram apenas até que esse dyno seja desligado ou reiniciado. Cada
  dyno é inicializado com uma cópia limpa do sistema de ficheiros mais
  recente. Isso é semelhante a quantos sistemas baseados em containers,
  como o Docker.
- Além disso, em operações normais, os dynos serão reiniciados todos os
  dias em um processo conhecido como "Cycling".
- Esses dois fatos significam que o sistema de ficheiros no Heroku não é
  adequado para armazenamento persistente de dados ou static files. Nos casos em que
  você precisa armazenar dados, recomendo o uso de um complemento de
  banco de dados, como o Postgres ou MySql (para dados) ou um serviço de
  armazenamento de ficheiros dedicado, como o AWS S3 (para ficheiros
  estáticos). Se você não deseja configurar uma conta na AWS para criar
  um bucket S3, também existem complementos que lidam com
  armazenamento e processamento de ficheiros estáticos.

Comment: Mais claro que isso impossível, parabéns.

Comment: Eu consigo fazer isso usando algum método gratuito e utilizando o App gratuito do Heroku? Por exemplo configurando um Docker? Sou iniciante e só fiz deploy no Heroku.

Comment: Viva, quanto ao Docker não precisas, eu só dei o exemplo. Agora um solução gratuita, deve existir, eu não conheço nem utilizo, tenho utilizado quase sempre Blob Storage da Azure, nos projetos que faço com Django só fiz uns anos atrás com Bucket S3 da AWS. Nos principais providers (nos 3 que indiquei), por exemplo o Azure consegues criar conta gratuita por 30 dias, mas penso que pede um modo de pagamento na mesma, apesar de não cobrarem nada, e não serve cartões virtuais.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas respostas!